# Hey parsing in string to character and string to number

Tags: javascript, parsing, object

Given a report of all student grades, return both the class average and the average of each student.

argument:
"Tom 91 85 115 100 99\nTim 98 111 98 91 95\nThomas 100 98 97 94 99"

**Output
{ "all": 98.06 , "Tom": 98, "Tim": 98.6, "Thomas": 97.6 }**

I am having trouble separating the characters and the numbers in string from. I need to dynamically spitting out the total average of all students, and total average each student by itself in object form(see bolded above). So if any event it will work with 10 or 2 students. Below is my code

```
function gradeCalulator (grades) {

  var arrayReport = report.split("\n");
  var i, j, results = {}; var array = []; 
  var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var numbers = "0123456789"
  for(i = 0; i < arrayReport.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < arrayReport[i].length; j++){
         if(alpha.indexOf(arrayReport[i][j]) > 0 ){
                results[arrayReport[i][j]] = arrayReport[i][j]
         } else if(numbers.indexOf(arrayReport[i][j]) > 0){
                results[arrayReport[i][j]] = arrayReport[i][j]
         }
      } 

  }
return results

}
gradeCalulator("Tom 91 85 115 100 99\nTim 98 111 98 91 95\nThomas 100 98 97 94 99");
```

Answer (score 0):

do this solve your problem

```
function gradeCalulator (reports)
{
    var students = grades.split('\n');
    var avg= {};

    var classsum = 0;
    for(var i in students)
    {
        var grades = students[i].split(' ');
        var sumgrade = 0;
        for(var j = 1; j < grades.length; j++) sumgrade+= parseInt(grades[j]);
        avg[grades[0]] = sumgrade / (grades.length - 1);
        classsum += avg[grades[0]];
    }

    avg.all = classsum / (students.length+1)
    return avg;
}

gradeCalulator("Tom 91 85 115 100 99\nTim 98 111 98 91 95\nThomas 100 98 97 94 99");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
var report = "Tom 91 85 115 100 99\nTim 98 111 98 91 95\nThomas 100 98 97 94 99";

var a = report.split('\n');

var result = {};
var sum = 0;
var st;

a.forEach(function(e) {
    st = e.split(' ');
    var name = st.shift();
    var s = 0;
    st.forEach(e => s += +e);
    sum += s;
    result[name] = s / st.length;
});

result.all = +(sum / a.length / st.length).toFixed(2);

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `String.split`, `Array.foreach`, `Array.reduce` and `Array.slice` functions:

```
function gradeCalulator(grades) {
    var arrayReport = grades.split("\n"), result = {}, items, allAvg = 0;
    arrayReport.forEach(function(v){
        items = v.split(' ');
        result[items[0]] = (items.slice(1).reduce(function(a,b){ return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); }))/(items.length - 1);
        allAvg += result[items[0]];
    });
    result['all'] = parseFloat((allAvg/Object.keys(result).length).toFixed(2));
    return result;
}

var result = gradeCalulator("Tom 91 85 115 100 99\nTim 98 111 98 91 95\nThomas 100 98 97 94 99");

console.log(result);
// Object {Tom: 98, Tim: 98.6, Thomas: 97.6, all: 98.07}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce`.

```
var list =  str.split('\n');

var sumInts = function (a, b) { return +a + +b; }
var toTwoDecimal = function (num) {
  return +parseFloat(Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}

function getGrades(arr) {
  var all = 0;
  var people = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
    var person = c.split(' ');
    var nums = person.slice(1);
    var sum = nums.reduce(sumInts) / nums.length;
    p[person[0]] = sum;
    all += sum;
    return p;
  }, {});
  people.all = toTwoDecimal(all / arr.length);
  return people;
}

getGrades(list); // { Tom: 98, Tim: 98.6, Thomas: 97.6, all: 98.07 }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cksdgf1c/1/)